# "Ешь на работе как дома". Перед "как" нужна ли занятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Ешь на работе как дома!" Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. Это обычное сравнение:

*Ешь на работе, как <ешь> дома!*

Не было бы глагола, открывающего предложение, запятая была бы лишней:

*На работе как дома!*

---

Ответы Справки Грамоты.ру:

**[Вопрос № 271809](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=271809)**

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в фразе: "Во всем мире, как
>   дома"?
>
> ---

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Запятая не нужна, поскольку слова "как дома" представляют собой
>   именную часть сказуемого.

**[Вопрос № 291815](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20291815)**

> Здравствуйте, уважаемые специалисты! Следует ли ставить запятую в
>   предложении: "Нам на работе, как дома"?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Запятая перед как не требуется.
>
> ---

Другие пояснения (цитирую лишь одно) из статьи "[Пять случаев, когда запятая перед «как» не нужна](https://mel.fm/pravopisaniye/7841235-commas_kak)".

> Пожалуй, самое простое правило, но при этом самое распространённое по
>   числу ошибок. Не нужно ставить запятую, если союз «как» имеет значение
>   «в качестве». Вероятно, вы помните, что сравнительные обороты мы
>   выделяем запятыми. Но отличить сравнительный оборот от значения «в
>   качестве» бывает непросто. «Аристотель вошёл в историю как ученик
>   Платона и учитель Александра Македонского». Вошёл в качестве кого? —
>   Ученика Платона и учителя Македонского. Рецепт один: внимательно
>   вчитываться в предложение и пытаться понять, есть ли здесь сравнение
>   или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится.

**Ешь на работе, как дома.** Аналог сравнительного предложения: Ешь на работе так, как будто  ешь дома.

Сравнить: **Чувствуешь себя на работе** как дома (=свободно). Здесь запятой нет, оборот в роли обстоятельства, которое нельзя обособить от глагола.

Пример: С ним мы совершили немало многодневных переходов и убедились, что в лесу он **чувствует себя как дома**.